# I was running an AVD on Android Studio and I got the following 2 errors. What do they mean?

Tags: android-sdk, virtualization, development, avd-manager, android-studio

Error number 1:

```
Emulator: E0809 05:21:56.677723102 2704 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1596930716.677712232","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}
```

Error number 2:

```
Emulator: KVM: injection failed, MSI lost (Operation not permitted)
```

The AVD works fine otherwise with no issues, I was just worried why I was getting these errors. I was not compiling an app or anything while running the AVD. The first error appeared when I started the AVD and the second error appeared upon shutting it down.

I get two other messages that don't seem to be errors but I am including them anyway (both of these below appear upon closing the AVD. Only the first error appears when the AVD is started):

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
```

The AVD is running **Android Q (API level 29) x86_64 image with Google APIs** and the device I am virtualizing is **Pixel 3**

Here are my PC specs:
16 gigs of RAM

- 16 Gbs of RAM
- Intel i3-8100 CPU
- Linux Kubuntu
- 120 gig SSD (that Linux installed on)
- 1TB HDD and another 240 GB ssd for Windows (unncessary info I think but I included it anyway)

Comment: Error in the emulator log are nothing unusual. If everything works you can ignore them.

Comment: @Robert you sure?